# Merging values of a column where ID is duplicated

Tags: sql, ms-access, concatenation, ms-access-2010

I have a table with an ID column that can contain duplicates, as it's used as a foreign key to match against my main table. There can be multiple results per id, as per the example below:

```
ID      FieldValue
1       This
2       Also this
1       and that
3       And additionally, this.
2       and, finally, this.
```

How would I go about merging the FieldValue column so that there was only one row per ID? E.g.

```
ID      FieldValue
1       This;and that
2       Also this;and, finally, this.
3       And additionally, this.
```

I wouldn't be concerned if the duplicate rows had to remain, e.g.

```
ID      FieldValue
1       This;and that
2       Also this;and, finally, this.
1       This;and that
3       And additionally, this.
2       Also this;and, finally, this.
```

As I could just run a DISTINCT query on them now that they're truly duplicates. Have been Googling for a while to no results; I suspect because it's something that has a few steps to it and I need to know what those steps are before a search would be fruitful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, @GordThompson, that's solved it. I was phrasing it wrong, but will leave this question here in case anyone else also phrases it wrong!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql you can try something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(FiledValue) As Result FROM tablename WHERE ID= '1'
```

Comment: Hi - thanks, but it's Access as per the tags.